# Providing default values to dynamic array to class in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, class, pointers

/* Hello Friends ... I am a beginner in C++ */

```
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>
using namespace std;

class A
{
    protected:
        int a,b;
    public:
        A():a(0),b(0){   }

};

int main()
{

 A *x;
 x = new A[20];
delete []x;
getch();
return 0;
}
```

My question is, How do we create a parameterised Constructor in Class A such that I could pass some default values while dynamically creating the array without using for loop. 
Also please tell me,What is the syntax of passing those values?

Comment: similar http://stackoverflow.com/questions/779655/objects-with-arguments-and-array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you want is this:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>
using namespace std;

class A
{
    protected:
        int a,b;
    public:
        A():a(0),b(0){   }
        A(int a, int b) : a(a), b(b) {  }

};

int main()
{
    A *x;
    x = new A[3]{ {10, 5}, {1, 2}, {4, 5} };
    delete []x;
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Note that you falsely had `delete []a;` in your code instead of the correct `delete []x;`.

The Constructor `A(int a, int b) : a(a), b(b) { }` initializes the member `a` and `b` with the parameter `a` and `b` respectively in the parameter list.

Then for the new call you give it a list with the arguments for the constructor grouped together in curly braces like this:

```
x = new A[3]{ {10, 5}, {1, 2}, {4, 5} };
```

Comment: Note this requires a real C++11 compiler。