# array of objects with multiple parameters

Tags: c++, arrays, class, object, parameters

How do I switch both parameters of the class to the object that I am creating? What is the syntax? (They must receive all the same parameters)

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class MyClass
{
    public:
        MyClass(int x,int y):value(x),value2(y)
        {
            //nothing
        }
        int value=10;
        int value2;
};

int main()
{
    MyClass ob1[5]; //Here! What is the correct syntax?
    cout << ob1[0].value << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Objects with arguments and array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/779655/objects-with-arguments-and-array)

Comment: Would this work?  MyClass ob1[5] = {(1,1),(2,2),(3,3),(4,4),(5,5)}? OR MyClass ob1[5] = {MyClass(1,1), MyClass(2,2), MyClass(3,3), MyClass(4,4), MyClass(5,5)}

Comment: FWIW, `std::vector` has a constructor to create N copies of something. It means an allocation and everything, though.

Comment: @George you're right, sorry, I had to specify... however, they had to be all the same! Thanks a lot to everyone!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try these two

```
 MyClass ob1[5] = {{1,1},{2,2},{3,3},{4,4},{5,5}};
```

OR

```
MyClass ob1[5] = {MyClass(1,1), MyClass(2,2), MyClass(3,3), MyClass(4,4), MyClass(5,5)};
```

Comment: Are you sure about the first one?

Comment: Yeah, the first one needs braces rather than parentheses.

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
MyClass ob1[] = {{1,2},{2,3},{3,4},{4,5},{5,6}};
```

(if you're using C++11 or later).

However, it would be better to use a std::vector or std::array.

Comment: Not if the constructor is marked `explicit` though. Just nitpicking.